# how to use postlayout in titanium (Alloy )imageview

Tags: javascript, android, titanium, appcelerator, titanium-alloy

Example code using postlayout in Titanium 3.x (Alloy) :

View:

```
 <Alloy>
    <Window class="container">
        <Label id="testLabel" onClick="doClick">Hello, World</Label>
        <ImageView id="testImgView" autoStyle="true" ></ImageView>
    </Window>
</Alloy>
```

Controller:

```
 $.testLabel.addEventListener('postlayout', function(e) {
        Ti.API.info('Label postlayout working!');
    });
     $.testImgView.image='default.png';
     $.testImgView.addEventListener('postlayout', function(e) {
        Ti.API.info('Img postlayout working!');
    });
     $.index.open();
```

Result:

```
[INFO][TiAPI   ( 2188)]  Label postlayout working!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are right, I've just tried your code on Android and it won't work with version 3.1.3GA. It must be a Bug.

If it's not an inconvenient for you you can use

```
<View id="testImgView" autoStyle="true" ></View>
```

and

```
$.testImgView.backgroundImage='/default.png';
```

And it will work

Or you can create an Issue [here](https://jira.appcelerator.org/secure/CreateIssue!default.jspa)

**Edit**

I've tried on iPhone Simulator SDK 6.1 and it fires imageView postlayout events well